# why my code always shows me the same mistake?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class GobbletError(Exception):
    pass

class Gobblet:
    def __init__(self, grosseur, no_joueur):
        self.grosseur, self.no_joueur = self.valider_gobblet(grosseur, no_joueur)

    def valider_gobblet(self, grosseur, no_joueur):
        self.grosseur = grosseur
        self.no_joueur = no_joueur
        grosseur = [0,1,2,3]
        no_joueur = [1,2]
        for i in grosseur:
            if i != int(i):
                raise GobbletError('La gosseur doit être un entier.')
                return i
            if i != 0 or i != 1 or i != 2 or i!=3:
                raise GobbletError('La grosseur doit être comprise entre 0 et 3.')
                return i
        for y in no_joueur:
            if y != int(y):
                raise GobbletError('Le numero du joueur doit être un entier.')
                return y
            if y != 1 and y != 2:
                raise GobbletError('Le numéro du joueur doit être 1 ou 2')
                return y

test = Gobblet(1,2)
print(test)
```

My code always shows me the same error, 'la grosseur doit etre comprise entre 0 et 3' I don't understand why.

Comment: It is not possible for `i` to simultaneously be all of those four values, so it will always be unequal to at least one of them (indeed, it will be unequal to at least *three* of them).  Perhaps you meant the opposite -- `if i not in grosseur` (although I'm not sure what purpose that serves since `i` is just an iteration over `grosseur` and will therefore always be one of those 4 numbers).

Comment: I believe you want `if i < 0 or i >3:`, or perhaps `if not i in range(4):`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems here:

1. This check is backwards:

```
if i != 0 or i != 1 or i != 2 or i!=3:
```

because it is asking if `i` is non-equal to *any* of those numbers, and since it can't be equal to *all* of them at once, it *must* be non-equal to *some* of them.  What I think you meant to do is:

```
if i not in range(4):
```

2. This line ensures that it's impossible to ever hit that check once it's written correctly:

```
grosseur = [0,1,2,3]
```

i.e. by overwriting the passed value of `grosseur`, you make it so that your validator is no longer validating it (even though you've already assigned the original value to `self.grosseur`)!  I'm also not sure if you want `grosseur` to be a list of ints -- my poor French hinders me here, but the sense I get from the rest of the code is that it's supposed to be a *single* int, meaning there's no point in iterating over it.

There's also a lot of random dead code -- for example it makes no sense to `return` after a `raise`, and it makes no sense for your validation function to initialize the instance when it's being called by the `__init__` function that's doing that anyway.

After deleting all the unnecessary code and fixing the checks so they test what I think you wanted them to test, here's what I think you were aiming for:

```
class GobbletError(Exception):
    pass

class Gobblet:
    def __init__(self, grosseur, no_joueur):
        self.grosseur, self.no_joueur = self.valider_gobblet(grosseur, no_joueur)

    def valider_gobblet(self, grosseur, no_joueur):
        if not isinstance(grosseur, int):
            raise GobbletError('La gosseur doit être un entier.')
        if grosseur not in range(0, 4):
            raise GobbletError('La grosseur doit être comprise entre 0 et 3.')
        if not isinstance(no_joueur, int):
            raise GobbletError('Le numero du joueur doit être un entier.')
        if no_joueur not in range(1, 3):
            raise GobbletError('Le numéro du joueur doit être 1 ou 2')
        return grosseur, no_joueur

test = Gobblet(1, 2)
print(test)
```